# How to check if an attribute resides within an element?

Tags: xml, xpath, schematron

I want to check if there is an inline stylesheet within the document, but I am not sure how to pick descendant attributes of an element as "style" attribute could be attached to any element within the body element. This is the current xpath I write:

```
descendant::@*[self::@style]
```

But the parser throws error saying: "Unexpected token "@" after axis name". Can anyone tell me how do I fix it or there is another way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you are looking for any element anywhere within the document that has an `@style` attribute I think.

If you want the element that contains the attribute you want to the following:

```
descendant::*[@style]
```

That will return all descendant elements of the current node that have an `@style` attribute. If you wanted the attribute itself you would be better off using something like:

```
descendant::*[@style]/@style
```

That will find you all the style attributes themselves.

Comment: `descendant::*` will give the wrong answer unless the context node is `/`, in which case it's equivalent to `//*`. `/descendant::*[@style]/@style` is equivalent to `/descendant::*/@style` is equivalent to `//*/@style` is equivalent to `//@style`.

Answer (score 2):

Use this XPath: `//@style`, it will select all attributes `style`

Answer (score 0):

@Kirill gave the correct answer regarding how to fix

```
descendant::@*[self::@style]
```

by using

```
//@style
```

But for those who want to know *why* the initial XPath doesn't work, and whether there's a variant using `self::` that would work...

Remember that `@` is an abbreviation for the `attribute::` axis. So `self::@foo` is shorthand for `self::attribute::foo`. But syntactically, there can only be one axis in a location step. That's why the parser rejects `self::@style`: it has two axes.

There's something else interesting going on here. You might think you could fix the expression as follows:

```
//@*[self::style]
```

(Ignore for the moment the fact that this is needlessly more complex that `//@style`. You start trying expressions like this when you want all attributes *except* `style`, e.g. `//@*[not(self::style)]`.)

This expression parses and runs without errors. The first part, `//@*`, matches all attribute nodes in the document. And you might think (as I did) that the predicate `[self::style]` will evaluate to a truthy value whenever its context node is a `style` attribute.

But we would be wrong. If we try it, we'll get an empty nodeset. Why? If the context node is an attribute node, and the `self::` axis contains only the context node, and the attribute's name matches the name that comes after `self::`, shouldn't the expression in the predicate yield that attribute node as its result?

On p. 1228 of XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0 (4th ed.), the glossary definition of Self Axis explains:

> The *principal node kind* of the self axis is *elements*, which means
>   that when the context node is an *attribute*, an axis *step* of the
>   form `self::*` or `self::xyz` **will not select** that attribute [bold emphasis mine].

However, in XPath 2.0, you can use `self::attribute(style)`. I.e. you can use a KindTest instead of a NameTest.

Michael Kay goes into quite a bit of detail on the rules for what kinds of nodes can be matched by a NameTest on p. 695.